# How to use an inner join of 3 database tables with unique 4 columns in VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-update, inner-join, oledb, dbf

I need to run a query from VB.NET that needs to inner join 3 database tables with 4 unique columns. I have the example below to join 2 tables with 3 unique columns.

```sql
update LBSTS as t1 
inner join GSDTS as t2 on t1.[PNM] = t2.[PNM] AND t1.[NOD] = t2.[NOD] AND t1.[ITM] = t2.[ITM] 
set t1.[CIA] = t2.[CIU] 
WHERE t1.PNM=@PNM
```

Given this example data:

TABLE NAME : GSDTS

| PNM | ITM | QTY | CIU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | TEST R 1001 | 10 | 20000 |
| 1000 | TEST R 1002 | 20 | 10000 |

TABLE NAME : GSGTS

| PNM | DTS | SAC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 06/12/2022 | 01-01 |

TABLE NAME : LBSTS

| RFN | DTS | ITEM | QTY | CIA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 06/12/2022 | TEST R 1001 | 10 | 1 |
| 1000 | 06/12/2022 | TEST R 1002 | 20 | 1 |

NOTE :
COLUMN SAC IS SAME WITH COLUMN RFN

COLUMN CIU IS SAME WITH COLUMN CIA

SET FOR UPDATE COLUMN CIA

[image: EXAMPLE TABLE]

How can I change this to also include the `CIA` column from the `LBSTS` table?

this Desired output :

TABLE NAME : GSDTS

| PNM | ITM | QTY | CIU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | TEST R 1001 | 10 | 20000 |
| 1000 | TEST R 1002 | 20 | 10000 |

TABLE NAME : GSGTS

| PNM | DTS | SAC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 06/12/2022 | 01-01 |

TABLE NAME : LBSTS

| RFN | DTS | ITEM | QTY | CIA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 06/12/2022 | TEST R 1001 | 10 | 20000 |
| 1000 | 06/12/2022 | TEST R 1002 | 20 | 10000 |

NOTE :
COLUMN SAC IS SAME WITH COLUMN RFN

COLUMN CIU IS SAME WITH COLUMN CIA

SET FOR UPDATE COLUMN CIA

[image: Desired output]

Comment: I see this is an OleDb connection, but not what kind of database this is connecting to. The exact syntax for UPDATE + JOIN varies considerably between different kinds of database, so that is important to know here, and we won't be able to fully answer the question without it. Also, the VB is incidental to the question. I suggest removing it, and only showing the SQL command. Finally, it's not clear what you want to do with the `CIA` column once we have it. So unfortunately, this question is not answerable as it is and I have to vote to close it :(

Comment: Might also help if you can also add your intended output to the question

Comment: Purely a SQL question, as @JoelCoehoorn hinted at, if you strip the vb code except for the SQL statement, the question is unchanged. Realize this, and tag the question appropriately, and you may get better help.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , Thank you for your reply. the database I use is DBF or dbase

Comment: @djv , Thank you for your recommendations

Comment: This is an improvement, but the SQL command references an STFTS table that is not shown. Additionally, screen shots are not an good way to show sample data or results. It makes it much harder for us to help you, because we can't copy/paste the data into a test system or our answer. It's enough friction a lot of the people who might answer will instead just move on to the next question. Instead, you should post the sample data as [formatted text.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn , thank you for reply from you , sorry I was late replying, I have updated the text format as per the recommendation from you. For the STFTS table you mean actually it's just a sql instance but I've changed it to LBSTS